# How to find the first cron job process complete or still running?

Tags: php, cron

I hvave a cron job that is doing some updates. After completion of that process i need to run another cron job for inserting that updated records into another table.For this I am trying this script.

```
 $output = shell_exec('ps -C php -f');
if (strpos($output, "php do_update.php")===false) { 
  shell_exec('php insert_process.php');
}
```

But it is not doing any thing and i am getting ps is not internal / external command.
So how can I find that first cron job execution is completed or not?Once that is executed then i will run the second cron for inserting data. Any holp would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some kind of a lock file.

First file:

1. at the beginning of the first script create empty file on the disk called `lockfile.txt` (or any other name)
2. at the end remove the file from the disk

Second file

1. check if the file called `lockfile.txt` exists, if not - run the code

Answer (score 1):

you can use `flock` on running the `do_update.php` add a lock to it and in

```
`insert_process.php` run the process if your previous lock is released
```

in your `do_update.php` add this

```
$fp = fopen("lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {

  //do your process

  flock($fp, LOCK_UN); //release the lock

}
```

in your `insert_process.php` add this

```
$fp = fopen("lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) { // checks for the lock

// do your process
}
```